# registring a wcf service with Castle Windsor

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor, wcffacility, windsor-facilities

I have a very simple service which works fine when not using Castle (which shows that the other codes are correct).
I changed my svc file to the following:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="Reporting.WebService.ReportingWebService" Factory="Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.DefaultServiceHostFactory, Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration"  %>
```

and register the service using xml as follow:

```
  <component id="Reporting.WebService.ReportingWebService"
           service="Reporting.WebService.IReportingWebService, Reporting.WebService"
           type="Reporting.WebService.ReportingWebService, Reporting.WebService">
</component>
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Could not find a component with name Reporting.WebService.ReportingWebService, did you forget to register it?]   Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WindsorServiceHostFactory`1.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
....
```

Any idea why it is not registered? ?

----update ----

I have this in windsor configuration:

```
<facilities>
    <facility id='wcf'
          type='Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WcfFacility,
                Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration' />
</facilities>
```

and ReportingWebService is implimented in another assembly.

Comment: Is ReportingWebService in the same assembly as the website or in a separate assembly? Have you registered the WcfFacility?

Comment: Please see update to question.

Comment: Think you missed something in the update :). Never mind I think it has given me an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see anything wrong with the wire up which leads me to think that either it cannot find your assembly or maybe the type has not been loaded. Because your webservice is referenced in another assembly make sure that it is referenced in the web project. Alternatively switch to doing your wire up in your Global.asax in code which will force you to reference the assembly and load the type:

```cs
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>()
         .Register(Component.For<IReportingWebService>().ImplementedBy<ReportingWebService>());

//Additional wire up

//If you are using Windsor 3.0 and above then the following is not needed
DefaultServiceHostFactory.RegisterContainer(container.Kernel);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way that I add some assembly to configuration in a way that they are not referenced by my project directly, but windows load them and use obkects from them?

Comment: @user654019 do you mean that you want to drop the dll in manually and update the configuration to use the new dll.

Comment: yes, I want to make sure that there is no reference to my service implementation, only reference to project that has the interface definition.

Comment: @user654019 was you issue that you were having previously because you did not have a reference to the assembly in your web project? If that is the case you can do what you want as long as you remember to copy the assembly with the service into your websites bin folder everytime you build the WcfService.